# solr DIH: RegExTransformer

Tags: java, regex, solr, regex-lookarounds, dataimporthandler

Currently, I need to apply a transformation on bellow third column:

```
ACAC | 0 | 01
ACAC | 0 | 0101
ACAC | 0 | 0102
ACAC | 0 | 010201
```

I need to transform `"010201"` to `"01/02/01"`.

So first I need to:

1. trim all ending `0` characters
2. split each 2 numbers and add `"/"` character.

The context of this transformation is inside [solr data import handler transformers](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/uploading-structured-data-store-data-with-the-data-import-handler.html#the-regextransformer), but it's using java regex library internally.

Is there anyway to get that?

I've tried using this regex:

Currently, I need to apply a transformation on bellow third column:

```
ACAC | 0 | 01
ACAC | 0 | 0101
ACAC | 0 | 0102
ACAC | 0 | 010201
```

I need to transform `"010201"` to `"01/02/01"`.

So first I need to:

1. trim all ending `0` characters
2. split each 2 numbers and add `"/"` character.

The context of this transformation is inside [solr data import handler transformers](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/uploading-structured-data-store-data-with-the-data-import-handler.html#the-regextransformer), but it's using java regex library internally.

Is there anyway to get that?

```
(\d[1-9]{1})
```

it tokens me:

```
01/04/01/
```

And would need:

```
01/04/01
```

Replace expression is:

$&/

Any ideas?

Comment: Good, so you have something working. Try `(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})\d*$` and replace with `$1/$2/$3`. I am curious why you use `$&`, in Java, `$0` is used to replace with the whole match.

Comment: Based on the docs, `<field column="colname" regex="(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})\d*$" replaceWith="$1/$2/$3"/>`

Comment: group number is not fixed to 3. I mean, I need to catch all pairs of 0[1-9] groups, throwing up all ending '0'... I mean, `010101040000` -> `01/01/01/04`... or `010100000000` -> `01/01`...

Comment: If you mean that, you would need a conditional replacement pattern and Java's regex engine does not support one.

Comment: I don't quite figure out. I need to append an `\` after each group captured. Here there is no condition, isn't it?

Comment: You want to replace with a different amount of `/` and various amount of matches. It is not possilbe without a lambda, or callable  in the replacement argument. Or, if it is supported, run several replacements on end, can you?

Comment: There would be any possibility to trim all ending "0"...?

Comment: If you can run it in 2 steps, yes: `0+$` => empty string, and then `\d{2}(?=(?:\d{2})+$)` => `$0/`

Comment: Look [here](https://regex101.com/r/BNTZRi/1), the `/` at the end will still be there if you  want to do everything with one regex.

Comment: I've solved trailing '0' triming them on database.

Comment: Can you please remove the 0s at the end of your input in the question? Does the above regex yields the expected output eventually? Is it `<field column="colname" regex="\d{2}(?=(?:\d{2})+$)" replaceWith="$0/" />`, https://regex101.com/r/BNTZRi/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
\d{2}(?=(?:\d{2})+$)
```

Replace with `$0/`, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zgRMIU/1/).

**Details**

- `\d{2}` - two digits
- `(?=(?:\d{2})+$)` - a positive lookahead that makes sure there are one or more occurrences of double digits up to the end of string.

The `$0` in the replacement stands for the whole match.

In the [`RegExTransformer`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/uploading-structured-data-store-data-with-the-data-import-handler.html#the-regextransformer) code, use

```xml
<field column="colname" regex="\d{2}(?=(?:\d{2})+$)" replaceWith="$0/" />
```