# Remove trailing "00" and and an slash

Tags: java, regex

I know some time ago I asked two related questions about next issue:

- [Java RegEX: Remove trailing slash after substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64767747/java-regex-remove-trailing-slash-after-substitution)
- [solr DIH: RegExTransformer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64695028/solr-dih-regextransformer)

Nevertheless, I don't quite figure out how to change regex in order to adapt to the next behavior:

My strings are like:

```
"010000000000" -> "01"
"011000000000" -> "01/10"
"011003000000" -> "01/10/03"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please don’t repeat the tags unnecessarily in your question titles.

Comment: You may make the task equal to the previous one if you insert `/` after each two digits, say with `..(?!$)` => `$0/` regex substitution.

Comment: Are the input Strings fixed length? Instead of trying a one-shot 'replaceAll', have you considered using `Pattern` and `Matcher`?

Comment: @ThomasTimbul OP is using a Java regex flavor with [RegExTransformer](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/uploading-structured-data-store-data-with-the-data-import-handler.html#the-regextransformer), see the [first OP's question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64695028/3832970).

Comment: Jordi, I have to repeat: you can't use a single regex replace method call to insert something not present in the string before and remove something simultaneously. You need two steps here.

Comment: Anyway, this is bordering semantic parsing, which isn’t a good fit for regular expressions. Regex describe *character-level* properties of a string. But your requirements go beyond the character level, to the level of *meaning*. There are ways of expressing this, but it’s not obvious that a single, fixed regex string replacement can insert the necessary delimiters.

Comment: Maybe first remove trailing zero's using [`(?:00)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/UbPhxO/4), and right after you add the slashes using [`(\d\d)(?!$)`](https://regex101.com/r/UbPhxO/5)